# Webpack 3 config to load files relative to the app root

Tags: webpack

Webpack 2 had a [`resolve.root`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root) configuration to set the application root.

What's the new Webpack 3 configuration?

Comment: Found it: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/